# What are the various ways to swap 2 variables

Tags: algorithm

I know about these. Is there any other ways as well? And which one is better?

1. Using temporary Variables
2. Using some Arithmetic operation
3. Using bitwise XOR operation

I believe the best approach is the XOR implementation. Any suggestions?

Comment: Better can mean many things.  In many/most cases "better" will be whatever is clearest to the person reading the code, so that's probably (a).

Comment: Option b and c only work for arithmetic types. c only works if you do some ugly trickery or overload the operator for the specific type.

Comment: Note that the XOR method only works when the data is of the same length.  For example, you can't use it to swap strings.

Comment: There may also be a primitive machine operation for swapping.

Comment: `primitive machine operations for swapping` can end up being slower if it's one of those legacy CISC operations that are now depreciated in favor of more RISC like ops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything that doesnt use temporary variable/register is guaranteed not to work always. Hence NOT advised to use it.

Bitwise XOR swap  doesnt work on same variable.(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Reasons_for_avoidance_in_practice)

'Arithmetics without temp variable swap' will have overflow issues.

Also note that if you do a simple swap using temporary, compiler is smart enough to convert it  to assembly without using temp variable. If you try to over-smart it, then

1. Your code will end equal or slower AND
2. Your code will be less readable for sure.

Comment: What's non-portable about XOR swap? I know it's sometimes slower then a dedicated machine instruction or other optimization and has issues if you swap two variables at the same address, but I fail to see what isn't portable about its behavior.

Comment: @0x5f3759df: How do you XOR swap some arbitrary object then? Say, a custom class?

Comment: @Mike Bantegui: I was interpreting portability as big/little endian or implementation-defined portability rather then ability to operate on a multitude of types.

Comment: @0x5f3759df my-typo.  I grouped them with wrong reason. I have already separated them out.
I am digging effect of BIT XOR on float variable meanwhile. :)

Comment: Non portability of XOR : 
Seems there is a portability issue on machines that dont use 2's compliement where sign could get flipped with XOR un-wantedly.

Comment: @Ajeet I understand that you can end up with a negative zero but I don't see how or why it'd be converted to a normal zero before the swap had completed.

Comment: `compiler is smart enough to convert it to...` is a rather sweeping statement that may or may not hold any water. Or may even be entirely irrelevant in the case of interpreted code, anyway +1 for the best thing is that which is guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 1):

These two binary operations `#` and `@` are inverses of each other, the following algo will also swap the values of a and b:

```
a = a # b
b = a @ b
a = a @ b
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just to note. This only works when you can define the options `#` and `@` on whatever types you're using. This means that `c = a; b = a; a = c;` is the most general and easy to use swap.

Comment: He asked for any other way to swap, thats what i answered. Any of these ways can be used for swapping, according to given conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the temporary variable solution is much better because:

- It is easy to read
- Can be used between multiple types
- Results is no arithmetic/logical operation
- No overflow related problem
- One extra memory space is not a huge overhead

Checkout these links:

- http://c-faq.com/misc/swapnotemp.html
- http://c-faq.com/expr/xorswapexpr.html

Answer (score 0):

Also possible is tuple unpacking:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86882M, Nov 30 2010, 10:35:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = 4
>>> b = 23
>>> a, b = b, a
>>> a
23
>>> b
4
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your language and the complexity of your options, an option d) is to swap internal pointers.  For example, if you have your own string object (in practice you'd use the standard library of your favorite language), it might contain a integer length and a pointer to the memory to store the string.  When swapping instances of the string object you'd swap only the length and the pointer to the data, not the data itself.